# Sqlite null pointer exception

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, jdbc

I do not know what's wrong with my code, got really confused with it.

```
btnDone.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            enterproject1 obj1 = new enterproject1();
            String   pn = obj1.getprojectname();
            Connection conni = null;

            try {
                  String query=("insert into " + obj1.getprojectname() + " (engname,engpass,startingdate,estdate) values(?,?,?,?)");
                  PreparedStatement pst= conni.prepareStatement(query);

                  pst.setString(1, engineername.getText());
                  pst.setString(2, engpass.getText());
                  pst.setString(3, startingdate.getText());
                  pst.setString(4, estdatee.getText());
                  pst.execute();
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Saved!");

                  System.out.println(pst.toString());

                  pst.close();
                } catch ( Exception e ) {
                  System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );

                  System.exit(0);
                }
               dispose();
               WindowProjectAdmin blue = new WindowProjectAdmin();
        }
    });
    btnDone.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
    btnDone.setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
    btnDone.setBounds(332, 327, 97, 38);
    contentPane.add(btnDone);
}
```

}

Should work right? Gives me Null pointer exception. The obj1 is a value from another class, I'm pretty sure the call is being made correctly too. Thank you for your time ^-^

Comment: Please either tell us on which line the `NullPointerException` happened, or, better yet, show us the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you initialise your connection variable to null

```
Connection conni = null;
```

and then use it here:

```
PreparedStatement pst= conni.prepareStatement(query);
```

conni is still null at this point hence a null pointer exception.

Comment: After doing that it says 
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "(": syntax error)

Comment: This indicates that the SQL command has a syntax error.  What does `obj1.getprojectname()` return?  My suspicion is that this is causing the syntax error by inserting some invalid SQL into the command

Comment: It returns a text value from a text field in another class. It does return I believe.

Comment: Please post the value of the query string variable